# Rails 7: Stimulus Rails Nested Form not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I am trying to follow the instrcutions mentioned here

https://www.stimulus-components.com/docs/stimulus-rails-nested-form/

but when I add the import statement

```
import NestedForm from 'stimulus-rails-nested-form'
```

i see the following error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/stimulus-rails-nested-form/dist/stimulus-rails-nested-form.mjs 2:16-17
Can't import the named export 'Controller' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

below is my `app/javascript/controllers/application.js`

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import NestedForm from 'stimulus-rails-nested-form'

const application = Application.start()
// application.register('nested-form', NestedForm)
// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }
```

below are the contents of my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.1",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-webpack-helpers": "^1.0.1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.4",
    "node": "^16.20.1",
    "stimulus-rails-nested-form": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

I am on rails `Rails 7.0.3`. Any help on what could be missing would be great, Thanks.

Comment: What versions of stimulus and stimulus-rails-nested-form are you using?

Comment: stimulus": "^3.2.1" & "stimulus-rails-nested-form": "^4.1.0", i have also updated the question with my package.json file

Comment: Using importmap instead of yarn solves the problem

Answer (score 3):

My Javascript fu, is not good enougth, but it seems this is a bug in *stimulus-rails-nested-form*. Its '.mjs' file, the default module entrypoint, imports *@hotwired/stimulus* in an incorrect way. As the error mentions only default export is available in the module, but a named import it been done.

*stimulus-rails-nested-form* uses a named import [here](https://unpkg.com/browse/stimulus-rails-nested-form@4.1.0/dist/stimulus-rails-nested-form.mjs), like this

```js
import { Controller as n } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

class r extends n { ... }
```

As the error mentions, the imported module only has a default export, so it should be imported like this:

```js
import Stimulus from "@hotwired/stimulus"

class r extends Stimulus.Controller { ... }
```

Since this requires a library change, until then, it can be solved by importing from the UMD file that *stimulus-rails-nested-form* provides.

```
import NestedForm from 'stimulus-rails-nested-form/dist/stimulus-rails-nested-form.umd.js'
```

Comment: can you please provide a little more information as to whats going wrong and how the fix addresses it

Comment: I've updated the answer, hope it helps.